# Richfaces ExtendedDataTable selection question

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, richfaces

Please help. 
Have a look at http://richfaces-showcase.appspot.com/richfaces/component-sample.jsf?demo=extendedDataTable&sample=exTableSelection&skin=blueSky

You'll see nice "Cars marketplace" table with multiple selection support. You'll also notice that one of the selected rows appears in bold. What does this bold line mean at all? Is it managed somehow via methods of `org.richfaces.component.UIExtendedDataTable` or any other RF classes? Cant find an API for that line.

What I'm trying to do, is to create new item inside backing bean and force table selection to point to newly created item. I've managed to set selection via `setSelection()`, but I have no control over that bold line, it remains on it's previous position, please help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The bold style for the selected row is managed by the stylesheet shipped with richfaces .Each theme in the richfaces has their own stylesheet.  You can refer to the [official documentation ( It is still a draft version)](http://docs.jboss.org/richfaces/latest_4_0_X/Component_Reference/en-US/html/chap-Component_Reference-Tables_and_grids.html#sect-Component_Reference-richextendedDataTable-Style_classes_and_skin_parameters) to see which style classes are available for customizing the look and feel of the `rich:extendedDataTable`.

For example , `rf-edt-r-sel` or `rf-edt-r-act` define the style of the selected row,  you can override them  by declaring a style for these style class names in the page where you use `rich:extendedDataTable`

```
<style type="text/css">
.rf-edt-r-sel{
     background-color: yellow;
}

.rf-edt-r-act{
   font-weight: bold;    
   color: red;
}   
</style>
```

Reply to the comment:

The `RowKey` seems to be the row number of the extended table. If you want to get the underlying object (i.e. `InventoryItem` ) from the `UIExtendedDataTable` , you have  to  set the row number you want to retrieve using `setRowKey(selectionKey)` before calling `getRowData()` to get the actual object . So `dataTable.setRowKey(selectionKey)` is used to get the selected `InventoryItem`  from the `UIExtendedDataTable` in order to  put them into the `selectionItems` (which will be displayed in the "Selected Rows" box that is besides the extended table) . For the  purposes of `Object originalKey = dataTable.getRowKey();` and `dataTable.setRowKey(originalKey);` , you can refer to this [link](http://community.jboss.org/thread/162010) .

In richfaces 3.3 , I find `UIExtendedDataTable` has a method called setActiveRowKey()  , which seems can set the active record . But it is removed in the latest version of richfaces 4.0 CR1 .So maybe you can use the `UIExtendedDataTable` ['s java script API](http://docs.jboss.org/richfaces/latest_4_0_X/Component_Reference/en-US/html/chap-Component_Reference-Tables_and_grids.html#sect-Component_Reference-richextendedDataTable-JavaScript_API) to achieve the same effect .

You first define an `int` property called `boldRow` in your MBean . Then you will have a `<a4j:commandButton>` to call a Mbean 's method .This method will assign the row number that you want to select according to your logic. The `oncomplete` attribute of the button should call the `UIExtendedDataTable` 's JavaScript API to select a row  which row number is equal to `boldRow`, and then  use `render` attribute to  refresh the `UIExtendedDataTable`. So the `<a4j:commandButton>` and `<rich:extendedDataTable>`  should probably look like this:

```
 <a4j:commandButton value="Submit" action = "#{MBean.action}" render="#{rich:clientId('table')}"  
           oncomplete="#{rich:component('table')}.selectRow(#{MBean.boldRow}); #{rich:component('table')}.setActiveRow(#{MBean.boldRow});" />

<rich:extendedDataTable id="table" .....
................
</rich:extendedDataTable>
```

Comment: Thanks for link, but I still dont understand the code in http://docs.jboss.org/richfaces/latest_4_0_X/Component_Reference/en-US/html/chap-Component_Reference-Tables_and_grids.html#exam-Component_Reference-richextendedDataTable-Selecting_multiple_rows, method public void selectionListener(). There is a line 'dataTable.setRowKey(selectionKey)', always followed and rewritten by  'dataTable.setRowKey(originalKey)'. Why is that? Is it rowKey that responsible for bold line? I need and to control that bold selectio  via API.